# Valid Access Token failed to post in Facebook wall

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api

I have checked the post in facebook app.

It is getting an error.

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in

I checked the access token, It is valid. Then why did I receive this error?
Please advice.

Edit:

Actually I have added the Facebook Config in 2 files.
Second file will be called while the execution of First file.

First file:

```
include_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'XXX',
    'secret'=> 'XXX',
);
$facebook   = new Facebook($config);
$user_id    = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token   = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['fbe_token']  = $access_token;

if(!$user_id) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
        'scope' => 'create_event,rsvp_event,user_events,user_likes,email,publish_actions,read_stream,publish_stream,user_groups,user_activities,offline_access',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname/'
    )); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href   = '<?php echo $login_url; ?>';
    </script>
<?php
} else {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $_SESSION['fbuser'] = $me;
}
```

End of the file, 2nd file will be called in ajax.

Second file:

```
include_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'XXX',
    'secret' => 'XXX',
    'cookie' => true,
);
$facebook   = new Facebook($config);
$user_id    = $_SESSION['fbuser']['id'];

$access_token = $_SESSION['fbe_token'];
$me = $_SESSION['fbuser'];

$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
    array(
    'link'  => 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname/',
        'message' => 'message',
    'picture' => 'https://www.image.com/eee.jpg',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'access_token' => $access_token
));
```

It posted on my wall with above mentioned error in description area.

Comment: More info would be helpful (does the oauth require you send the token with each request?, what line is it failing at?, etc). And a code example, too, please.

Comment: @joseph4tw: Thanks. I have updated..Please check and let me know the issue.

Comment: @joseph4tw: how to check it "does the oauth require you send the token with each request?"..

Comment: I think you have an issue with your sessions. Are you using `session_start()`?

Comment: @joseph4tw: I have not shown that in above mentioned codes. But I have added in first line of both files.

Comment: @joseph4tw: I found a clue. When I change the link url, then it is working. But I need to give app url. If I post the link with app url, then I get the error in post. :(